# Heroku + Django + Sendgrid produces no error but emails don't get delivered

Tags: django, heroku, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid as smtp server and sending password reset email, but the emails are not getting delivered without error messages.

Current smtp settings in settings.py are as the following:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'appname@heroku.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Screen shots from sendgrid homepage also indicates that the emails were delivered but I couldn't get them at any of the addresses.

Is it because I did not set DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL or something? Thanks for your helps in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If our dashboard shows the email as delivered, it means that the mail server has received the message. However, there could be an issue blocking delivery between the mail server and the mail client. In that case you would need to investigate with the postmaster for the mail server.

Have you tried sending to multiple ISPs? Do you get the same result across multiple ISPs?

We also have support available via live chat, email and phone at http://support.sendgrid.com

*Disclaimer: I work for SendGrid.*

Comment: I have changed to MailGun addons on Heroku... Anyway Thank you for your comment! For now, I will just go with mailgun but I will try to find what the problem is later :)